# Join 2 Tables with match of sub-string from Table 1 for Table 2

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to join 2 tables based on below criteria:

- I would like to pick the substring from Table_A where "some_name" column has data like 'AB-FBb3' and then match it against Table_B by replacing FB with SC and then fetching "desc" details.

```
Table_A:
**AB  some_name     G_NAME      Status        some_time**
------------------------------------------------------------
AAA    Job1        xxxxxxxxx   Ended OK    2020-06-29 10:37:52
AAA    Job2        xxxxxxxxx   Ended OK    2020-06-29 10:37:52
BBB    AB-Job1     xxxxxxxxx   Ended OK    2020-06-29 10:37:52
BBB    AB-Job2     xxxxxxxxx   Ended OK    2020-06-29 10:37:52
BBB    AB-FBb3     xxxxxxxxx   Ended OK    2020-06-29 10:37:52

Table_B:
**RM  j_name           desc            rand_time**
----------------------------------------------------
111   Job1            Sometext    2020-06-29 06:30:51
111   AB-Job1         Sometext1   2020-06-29 09:31:52
222   AB-Job5         Sometext2   2020-06-29 09:34:11
222   DPF-AB-Job2     Sometext3   2020-06-29 03:39:33
222   SCb3            Sometext4   2020-06-29 11:32:23
```

Currently what I have (I would like to add on the above condition mentioned to this):

```
SELECT a.some_name,a.G_NAME,b.desc, 
               FROM Table_A a 
               LEFT JOIN Table_B b  
               ON b.j_name IN (a.some_name, 'DPF-' || a.some_name)
               where a.service_name like 'AB-%'
```

Any suggestions? Also the substring postion is not fixed. Would need to find the substring and then join the Tables.
[FYI: This is an extended question to my earlier question- hence posted as separate question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62850965/sql-select-table-columns-by-matching-table-1-with-2-conditions-in-table-2)

Comment: You need to imbricate two loops, with each ranges -i,j- being the length of each array.
When inside the innerloop, you can ommit the  i == j and do your comparisons and changes here.
You can translate this into sql commands.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer by trying an OR condition with the SUBSTR combined with INSTR:

```
SELECT a.some_name,a.G_NAME,b.desc, 
               FROM Table_A a 
               LEFT JOIN Table_B b 
               ON 
               (b.j_name IN (a.some_name, 'SC' || SUBSTR(a.some_name, 
               instr(a.some_name, 'FB')+2 ,3)))
               or
               (b.j_name IN (a.some_name, 'DPF-' || a.some_name))
               where a.service_name like 'AB-%'
```

I'm not sure if it's a perfection solution but if anyone has a better solution, please feel free to let me know.